# What is the correct way to delete a non-leaf node in an LDAP directory

Tags: directory, ldap

I have a non-leaf node in LDAP directory. I want to delete the node. 
One approach is to delete all the children from the bottom most level in the tree and then finally delete the non-leaf node. 
Is there any other approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server supports TreeDelete control(OID is 1.2.840.113556.1.4.805) then you can send it along with the delete request. Servers that support this control may advertise the availability of this in RootDSE's "supportedControl" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the API and the server allow you to delete a non-leaf node directly, that's the only approach.